# Is it possible to have a JwtAuthenticationToken instead of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken while using DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I set up a Spring authentification server but when I authenticate a user I see that my token is of type UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken while I was expecting JwtAuthenticationToken. I thought it was the default configuration.

I see that it's my custom authentication provider of type DaoAuthenticationProvider, who can only handle UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, who must be the responsible here.

I also see that there is a JwtAuthenticationConverter class who do the exact opposite of what I want.

The main reason I want to change the type of token, is that it seems more secure with RSA key, and I am currently missing the expiration timestamp attribute "exp".

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(getAuthenticationProvider());
}

public AuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    LimitingAttemptsDaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new LimitingAttemptsDaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    authProvider.setUtilisateurService(utilisateurService);
    return authProvider;
}
```

Here you can see my configuration of the server and of the resource server:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

    http.cors(withDefaults())
        .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
        .oidc(withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, @Value("${permit-all:[]}") String[] permitAll) throws Exception {

    http.oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()));

    http.formLogin(withDefaults())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers(Stream.of(permitAll)
                                                                          .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                                                                          .toArray(AntPathRequestMatcher[]::new))
                                                   .permitAll()
                                                   .anyRequest()
                                                   .authenticated());

    return http.build();
}
```

And my client:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityWebFilterChain clientFilterCHain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ServerProperties serverProperties,
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, @Value("${client-security-matchers:[]}") String[] securityMatchers,
    @Value("${client-permit-all:[]}") String[] permitAll) {

    final var clientRoutes = Stream.of(securityMatchers)
                                   .map(PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher::new)
                                   .map(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.class::cast)
                                   .toList();
    http.securityMatcher(new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(clientRoutes));

    http.oauth2Login(login -> {
        login.authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/ui/"));
        login.authenticationFailureHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationFailureHandler("/ui/"));
    });

    http.authorizeExchange(ex -> ex.pathMatchers(permitAll)
                                   .permitAll()
                                   .anyExchange()
                                   .authenticated());

    return http.build();
}
```